# Can I use the source code available in GitHub and customize?

Tags: android, github, open-source

This is the first I'm into open source and using GitHub, I have to develop the music app with some customization, can I use the source code available in Git hub and do the customization and release?

I feel this is not right way, Is it legal to do so?
Will there be any copyrights for that app?

Comment: I think this is normal ^^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / copyright / legal issues instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Comment: @Pang I'm unable to delete this question, since two people has already answered.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The project in question is https://github.com/kreed/vanilla respective the active fork https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla

The latter is licensed under [GPLv3](https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla/blob/master/LICENSE). An explanation what this implies can be found at https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3)

---

**Note: Legal advice should most likely involve talking to a lawyer.**

> can I use the source code available in Git hub and do the customization and release?

It depends on the license of the project you are using. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL is a very permissive license which allows you to do anything you want. Other licenses require you to share your souce code with anyone that requests it (GPL, Apache) and/or attribution to the project you used.

> will there be any copy rights for that app?

Images, sounds etc. most likely are copy righted. I do not know if this is the case for source code; for the code I would only look at the license.

---

Perhaps you can also ask the author of the project you want to use.

Comment: https://github.com/kreed/vanilla points to https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla as an active fork. https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla/blob/master/LICENSE is the GPL License v3. In there it is explained what you are allowed to do. 

The GPLv3 is explained here in plain English: https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3)

Comment: so you mean to say that I can't use any app from Github and do customization and release?

Comment: Man just do one thing! Do not copy the code but just make your own refering it

Comment: You may use the code as described on tldrlegal.com. It always depends on the project you are using.

Comment: For 1) You can use it if you adhere to the restrictions of the license. If there is no license, you must ask the author or simply decide not to use it. For 2) For code that is entirely written by yourself, you decide what happens with it. Open source, closed source, whatever. If you're using open source, you have to adhere to the restrictions outlined in the license.

Comment: I think you can use it, but just for sake of you and everyone please ask the author if possible

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments, I'll simply stop using it.:)

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of open source means you can use it freely and that is why github is there for us. If some one has copyright problem than he would not upload the repo. on github. That's simple! you can customize it and use it anywhere.

Comment: "Open Source" is not just free for use. Licensing implies some serious consequences; see different "legal cases" like http://www.pcworld.com/article/2893852/vmware-sued-for-alleged-gpl-license-infractions.html

Comment: But libraries are uploaded for free use

Comment: But you should use the owner name in credits some where in your app(Where you put credits)

Comment: Libraries follow the same restrictions as other applications: the license of the library tells you what you may do (some libraries may imply that only linking is allowed and/or that the library must be "replacable by a user compiled variant of that library") and what you must do (must dos often include "name the library and the license somewhere"). Uploading code to github is not automatically  "please do whatever you want with this", especially without license.

Comment: Your reasoning is completely false. Github specifically mentions that, in the absence of a license, a (relatively restrictive) license is assumed by github, only allowing others to view and fork a project.